# Is it possible to automatically send firebase notifications when a new post is published on Wordpress

Tags: php, android, wordpress, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I built an Android app for my `WordPress` blog. Right now, I manually send notifications (to subscribers) from `Firebase` console when a new post is published. This is really stressful and sometimes I forget to send it.

Please is there any way this process can be automated?

Comment: You will need to write some backend code to do that for you. It's not supported by Firebase.

Comment: @VladimirJovanović Please can you expatiate, I am not very good in php. I was thinking of some kind interface that listens for a new post and then sends a notification, but I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: I don't know how to explain it without writing a book :). You will need to create server-side in PHP, Java or some other language on your server (not on Firebase), that will take care of publishing new things and sending notifications afterward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible but you will need to make some modifications to the WordPress backend.

The publish_post trigger sounds like what you're looking for:

publish_post is an action triggered whenever a post is published, or if it is edited and the status is changed to publish.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post